# No bitcode included in skobbler SDK

Tags: ios, skmaps, bitcode

I installed the latest `ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK` pod and tried to archive to estimate the resulting application's size. Yet, clang was not quite happy:

> ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/Users/[redacted]/git/[redacted]/Pods/ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK/SKMaps.framework/SKMaps(SKRequestDataFactory.o)' was built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture armv7

Is there a bitcode version of the SDK or am I stuck not using bitcode?

Comment: At this moment this version is not available. This improvement is on "to do" list http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/7414-Enable-bitcode-for-iOS

Comment: Is there any update on this with the current version 3 of the SDK?

Comment: I am trying to publish an app right now, and Bitcode is disabled on 3.0 as well.